# Make the display hidden work for the empty innerhtml element

Tags: javascript

I have a form that takes in a name without space and a phone number.

I managed to get the form and the error messages to work but I couldn't find a way to hide the syle of the error when there's no message in it. It does the job in hiding the other subsequent error messages but not the first one, I found this out through Chrome's debugging tool.

I've tried iterating through all elements to find a blank innerHTML and make the error style hidden, but it didn't work, it couldn't find it.

Is there a way? Here's the code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let form = document.getElementById("formDetails");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        let haltSubmission = false;
        cleanPhoneError();
        cleanNameError();
        for (let i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
            if (!nameCheck(form.elements[i])) {
                haltSubmission = true;
            } else if (!matchingPhone(form, form.elements[i])) {
                haltSubmission = true;
            } else if (!lengthOfPhone(form.elements[i])) {
                haltSubmission = true;
            }
        }
        if (haltSubmission) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
}

function nameCheck(formInput) {
    if (formInput.id === "name") {
        let value = formInput.value, error = "", letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
            characters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;
        if (value === null || value === "") {
            error = "This field is empty.";
        }
        if (value !== "") {
            if (value.length < 3) {
                error = "This field has less than 3 characters.";
            }
            if (!value.match(letters)) {
                error = "Numbers detected. Please write your first name.";
            }
            if (!value.match(characters)) {
                error = "Special characters detected. Please write your first name.";
            }
        }
        errorMessage(formInput, error);
    }
    return true;
}

function matchingPhone(form, formInput) {
    if (formInput.id === "phone") {
        let error = "";
        let phone = form.phone.value;
        let retypedPhone = form.retypedphone.value;
        if (phone === retypedPhone) {
            return true;
        } else {
            error = "Phone numbers do not match.";
            phoneError(error);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function lengthOfPhone(formInput) {
    if (formInput.id === "phone") {
        let value = formInput.value, error = "";
        if (value === null || value === "") {
            error = "This field is empty.";
            phoneError(error);
            return false;
        } else if (value !== "") {
            if (value.length < 11) {
                error = "Invalid phone number, it has than 11 numbers.";
                phoneError(error);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


function errorMessage(selected, error) {
    let elem = document.createElement("span");
    elem.setAttribute("id", "nameError");
    elem.setAttribute("class", "error");
    let text = document.createTextNode(error);
    elem.appendChild(text);
    selected.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, selected.nextSibling);
    return selected;
}

function phoneError(error) {
    let phoneError = document.getElementById("phoneError");
    phoneError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    phoneError.innerHTML = error;
}

function cleanPhoneError() {
    let error = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (let i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {
        error[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function cleanNameError() {
    let error = document.getElementById("nameError");
    let errorMessage = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (let i = 0; i < errorMessage.length; i++) {
        if (errorMessage[i].id === "nameError") {
            error.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
label, button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
}

input, button {
    padding: 8px;
    width: 393px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body, button{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.error{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    background: #990000;
    padding: 5px 3px 5px 5px;
    width: 405px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <div id="form">
        <form id="formDetails" action="confirm.html">
            <div>
                <label for="name">* Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="phone">* Phone Number</label>
                <input type="phone" id="phone">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="retypedphone">* Retype Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="phone" id="retypedphone">
                <span id="phoneError"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the error variable represent, or what is its initial value?

Comment: @KinoBacaltos It's there to create a message. Initially, it is blank until it gets the error and creates a message out of it.

Comment: Have you tried assigning IDs to your empty elements, and then deleting them if you dont need them or are not using them? `element.remove()`

Comment: @KinoBacaltos Yup, the problem is still there. The first span with a blank innerHTML with a red bar isn't removed.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You need to modify your function `errorMessage(...)` to only append the element if there is an error message.</del>

<del>A simple `if` statement might be enough for your needs.</del>

---

**UPDATE**

Based on comment, I re-wrote the hiding/showing error logic, please have a look.  I think this is a bit more readable too

**See demo below**

```js
function cleanPhoneError() {
  hideElement("phoneError");
}

function hideElement(elementName) {
  let elementObj = document.getElementById(elementName);

  if (elementObj) {
    elementObj.innerHTML = "";
    elementObj.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
  }
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let form = document.getElementById("formDetails");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    let haltSubmission = false;
    cleanErrors();

    if (!validName()) {
      haltSubmission = true;
    }

    if (!validPhone()) {
      haltSubmission = true;
    }

    if (haltSubmission === true) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }, false);
}

function cleanErrors() {
  cleanPhoneError();
  cleanNameError();
}

function validName() {
  let nameObj = document.getElementById("name");

  if (nameObj) {
    let value = nameObj.value,
      error = "",
      letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
      numbers = /[0-9]+/,
      characters = /[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+/g;

    if (value === null || value === "") {
      error = "This field is empty.";

    } else if (value.length < 3) {
      error = "This field has less than 3 characters.";

    } else if (value.match(characters)) {
      error = "Special characters detected. Please write your first name.";

    } else if (value.match(numbers)) {
      error = "Numbers detected. Please write your first name.";
    }

    if (error !== undefined && error.trim() !== '') {
      displayErrorMessage(error, "nameError");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  displayErrorMessage("Unable to find Name field.", "nameError");
  return false;
}

function validPhone() {
  let phoneObj = document.getElementById("phone");
  let retypedPhoneObj = document.getElementById("retypedPhone");

  if (phoneObj && retypedPhoneObj) {
    let phoneValue = phoneObj.value;
    let retypedPhoneValue = retypedPhoneObj.value;

    if (phoneValue !== retypedPhoneValue) {
      displayErrorMessage("Phone numbers do not match.", "phoneError");
      return false;
    } else {
      return validateLengthOfPhone(phoneValue);
    }
  } else {
    displayErrorMessage("Unable to find Phone fields.", "phoneError");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validateLengthOfPhone(value) {
  let error = "";

  if (value === null || value === "") {
    error = "This field is empty.";
    displayErrorMessage(error, "phoneError");
    return false;

  } else if (value.length < 11) {
    error = "Invalid phone number, it has less than 11 numbers.";
    displayErrorMessage(error, "phoneError");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function displayErrorMessage(errorMsg, elementName) {
  if (errorMsg !== undefined && errorMsg.trim() !== '') {
    let elementError = document.getElementById(elementName);
    elementError.setAttribute("class", "error visible");
    elementError.innerHTML = errorMsg;
  }
}

function cleanPhoneError() {
  hideElement("phoneError");
}

function cleanNameError() {
  hideElement("nameError");
}

function hideElement(elementName) {
  let elementObj = document.getElementById(elementName);

  if (elementObj) {
    elementObj.innerHTML = "";
    elementObj.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
label,
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
}

input,
button {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 393px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body,
button {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.error {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  background: #990000;
  padding: 5px 3px 5px 5px;
  width: 405px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <div id="form">
    <form id="formDetails" action="confirm.html">
      <div>
        <label for="name">* Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <span id="nameError" class="error"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="phone">* Phone Number</label>
        <input type="phone" id="phone">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="retypedphone">* Retype Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="phone" id="retypedPhone">
        <span id="phoneError" class="error"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The only issue would be phone numbers, otherwise the name works well. Cheers!

Comment: @JinRi Your qustion talks about the first field only - I did not realize it was all the validation fields ;)